# Shared preference value not being changed upon trigger

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Here's my code where I'm executing a method if a condition is met. For some reason , value of 'NEWPINCO' is not changed to the 'value' that I'm passing. Am I doing something the wrong way ?

```
dynamic NEWPINCO;
      addAddressPersistent(dynamic value) async {
        NEWPINCO = '';
        print("VALUE PASSED FOR PINCODE : $value");
        final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        setState(() {
          prefs.setString('NEWPINCO', value);
          print("$NEWPINCO is the number");
        });
      }
```

OUTPUT of debug statements in console:

```
I/flutter ( 6129): VALUE PASSED FOR PINCODE : 281232
I/flutter ( 6129):  is the number
```

Does anybody know why isn't the value of NEWPINCO changing ? As you could notice, the value of NEWPINCO is '' as initialized during the method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared NEWPINCO as an empty string at the beginning of your code, yeah you're saving a String in shared_preferences with a key of NEWPINCO, but that's unrelated to your dynamic object

```
  dynamic NEWPINCO;
  addAddressPersistent(dynamic value) async {
    NEWPINCO = '';
    print("VALUE PASSED FOR PINCODE : $value");
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('NEWPINCO', value); //setting it's a Future
    setState(() {
      NEWPINCO = prefs.getString('NEWPINCO');
      print("$NEWPINCO is the number");
    });
  }
```